# Query Syntax против Method Syntax в LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Во время написания LINQ-запроса чем необходимо руководствоваться при выборе стиля написания запроса? Использовать синтаксис запроса (`Query Syntax`) или метода (`Method Syntax`)? Что лучше использовать?

На мой взгляд методы удобнее и писать и читать, чего не скажешь про синтаксис запроса. В каких случаях необходимо использовать синтаксис запроса, а в каких синтаксис метода?

Очень хотелось бы узнать подробнее и с примерами, когда и чем лучше тот или иной подход написания запроса. Из этой статьи [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397947.aspx) почему-то не все понял, да и есть места, где мое мнение отличается.

Comment: query syntax - переводится в method syntax, поэтому никакой разницы нет. Как больше нравится так и пиши

Comment: @Grundy, то есть никакого выигрыша в производительности, к примеру скорости выполнения или построении запроса на основании кода нет?

Comment: Абсолютно никакой разницы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Длинные и сложные запросы в синтаксисе методов могут стать нечитаемыми - особенно при частом использовании анонимных классов. Синтаксис же запроса скрывает эти анонимные классы от вас:

```
var q1 = trees.SelectMany(t => t.Leaves.Select(l => new { tree = t, leaf = l }))
  .OrderBy(x => x.leaf.color)
  .Select(x => x.tree.name);
```

Попробуйте переписать запрос выше без анонимного класса. А ведь в более длинных запросах могут появиться уже либо вложенные анонимные классы - либо постоянные копирования из одного анонимного класса в другой.

При использовании синтаксиса запроса многие анонимные классы успешно прячутся:

```
var q1 = from tree in trees
         from leaf in tree.Leaves
         order by leaf.Color
         select tree.Name;
```

Также в длинных запросах при использовании методов может быстро надоесть писать один и тот же префикс для каждого замыкания - в синтаксисе запроса же range variable определяется только 1 раз.

По этой причине в сложных запросах синтаксис запроса, как правило, предпочтительнее.

---

С другой стороны, некоторые вещи сделать в синтаксисе запроса просто невозможно.

К примеру, перегрузки методов, принимающие `IEqualityComparer`, могут быть вызваны только как методы.

Также синтаксис методов позволяет "накапливать" сложный запрос в переменной в зависимости от внешних условий - что полезно при обработке блоков фильтрации:

```
if (filters.Foo.HasValue) 
  q = q.Where(x => x.Foo == filters.Foo);

if (filters.Bar != null) 
  q = q.Where(x => x.Bar.Name == filters.Bar);
```

Comment: и еще иногда не хватает в query синтаксисе возможности использовать перегрузки, которые в callback принимают Index